# How do I suppress lines of code inside one function when that function is being called from within another function?

Tags: matlab, function, suppress, disp

I have two functions, one is called from inside of another. I want certain parts of the first function to not execute when being called within the second function.

```
function vvec = vecVelocity(varargin);
%must be preceded with a 'syms var real' declaration where var is
%the parameter of your vector function

if nargin > 1 & nargin < 3
   r = [sym(varargin(1:end))];
elseif nargin > 3 
    disp('too many inputs')
    return
else r = [sym(varargin(1))];
end

if length(r) < 3
    r = [r,0];
end

dr = diff(r);
uT = vecUnitTan(r);
speed = sqrt(sum(dr.^2));
v = speed*uT;
vvec = matlabFunction(v);
disp(['Simplified Symbolic Form: ' char(simplify(sym(vvec)))]);
```

I would like to suppress this last line **disp(...)** from appearing when I call this following second function from the command window

```
function speed = vecSpeed(r);
%must be preceded with a 'syms var real' declaration where var is
%the parameter of your vector function

v = sym(vecVelocity(r));
sp = sqrt(sum(v.^2));
speed = matlabFunction(sp);
disp(['Simplified Symbolic Form: ' char(simplify(sym(speed)))]);
```

At the moment, calling the vecSpeed function, causes a bunch of statements to be displayed from other preceding functions that are called from within the vecSpeed function (and some that are called from within the vecVelocity function), but I only want the **disp(...)** statement from the vecSpeed function to be called, not any of the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first function, you can put a block of codes in

```
if numel(dbstack) == 1
  % Your code block
end
```

to prevent them to be executed unless the function is being called directly from Command Window.

Another way is to check for existence of some variables like `debug_1`, `debug_2` etc.. which you can pass from the 2nd function when you call the 1st function.